# add remove edit row from table

Tags: javascript, html

I need help please in javascript

- how to make add new row for all columns with same properties of old rows it must add "remove button" for new row?
- how can I except cell which have button from editing?
- how to make confirm message when press remove button?

I tried the scripts below but they are not working as I want

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        table {
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }

        td,
        th {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #dddddd;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>


    <div class="ht-65 bd bg-gray-100 pd-x-20 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">

        <div class="mg-l-auto">
            <button class="btn btn-primary active" title="Add New" onclick="addRow()">Add New Row</button>

        </div>
    </div><!-- ht-65 -->

    <p>Click on a table cell to edit it. Press OK or CANCEL when you finish.</p>

    enter code html here
    <table id="bagua-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>col1</th>
                <th>col2</th>
                <th>col3</th>
                <th>col4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td class="nw"><strong>Northwest</strong>
                    <br>Metal
                    <br>Silver
                    <br>Elders
                </td>
                <td class="n"><strong>North</strong>
                    <br>Water
                    <br>Blue
                    <br>Change
                </td>
                <td class="ne"><strong>Northeast</strong>
                    <br>Earth
                    <br>Yellow
                    <br>Direction
                </td>
                <td class="ne"><button class="btn btn-light bd btn-block" style="width:100px"> remove</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="w"><strong>West</strong>
                    <br>Metal
                    <br>Gold
                    <br>Youth
                </td>
                <td class="c"><strong>Center</strong>
                    <br>All
                    <br>Purple
                    <br>Harmony
                </td>
                <td class="e"><strong>East</strong>
                    <br>Wood
                    <br>Blue
                    <br>Future
                </td>
                <td class="ne"><button class="btn btn-light bd btn-block" style="width:100px"> remove</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="sw"><strong>Southwest</strong>
                    <br>Earth
                    <br>Brown
                    <br>Tranquility
                </td>
                <td class="s"><strong>South</strong>
                    <br>Fire
                    <br>Orange
                    <br>Fame
                </td>
                <td class="se"><strong>Southeast</strong>
                    <br>Wood
                    <br>Green
                    <br>Romance
                </td>
                <td class="ne"><button class="btn btn-light bd btn-block" style="width:100px"> remove</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

my scripts

```
   <!--add row-->
   <script>
        function addRow() {
          var table = document.getElementById("bagua-table");
          var row = table.insertRow(1);
          var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
          cell1.innerHTML = "";
        }
        </script>
```

```
        <!--remove row-->
      <script>  
       $('.table tbody').on('click','.btn',function(){
           $(this).closest('tr').remove();
       });
   </script>
```

```
<!--edit cell-->
  <script>
      let table = document.getElementById('bagua-table');

let editingTd;

table.onclick = function(event) {

  // 3 possible targets
  let target = event.target.closest('.edit-cancel,.edit-ok,td');

  if (!table.contains(target)) return;

  if (target.className == 'edit-cancel') {
    finishTdEdit(editingTd.elem, false);
  } else if (target.className == 'edit-ok') {
    finishTdEdit(editingTd.elem, true);
  } else if (target.nodeName == 'TD') {
    if (editingTd) return; // already editing

    makeTdEditable(target);
  }

};

function makeTdEditable(td) {
  editingTd = {
    elem: td,
    data: td.innerHTML
  };

  td.classList.add('edit-td'); // td is in edit state, CSS also styles the area inside

  let textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
  textArea.style.width = td.clientWidth + 'px';
  textArea.style.height = td.clientHeight + 'px';
  textArea.className = 'edit-area';

  textArea.value = td.innerHTML;
  td.innerHTML = '';
  td.appendChild(textArea);
  textArea.focus();

  td.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd",
    '<div class="edit-controls"><button class="edit-ok">OK</button><button class="edit-cancel">CANCEL</button></div>'
  );
}

function finishTdEdit(td, isOk) {
  if (isOk) {
    td.innerHTML = td.firstChild.value;
  } else {
    td.innerHTML = editingTd.data;
  }
  td.classList.remove('edit-td');
  editingTd = null;
}
  </script>
```

```
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: unclear ! Could you describe the issue in an understandable way.

Comment: so when add row button gets pressed that row is cloned and also append to it a remove button?

Comment: how to make add new row for all columns with same properties of old rows it must add "remove button" for new row?
when  i add a new row for table the problem it added in first cell only in the first column i want to add row with cells for all columns in row not for first column only with button as you see in html code and javascript . this is for first question

Comment: yes copy it but with clear value

Answer (score 1):

In here you have working example for adding and removing rows.

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>asdasd</th><th>asdadsdasd</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table_body">
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="add_row_button">Add row</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var tableBody = document.getElementById("table_body")
  var addRowButton = document.getElementById("add_row_button")
  var rowId = 0;
  addRowButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var row = tableBody.insertRow(0)
    row.id = `table_row_${++rowId}`

    console.log(row.id) 
    row.addEventListener('click', function() { deleteRow(row.id) })
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0)
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1)

    cell1.innerHTML = "Value of cell 1"
    cell2.innerHTML = "VAlue of cell 2"
  })

  function deleteRow(rowId){
    console.log("DELETEING")
    var elementToRemove = document.getElementById(rowId)
    elementToRemove.parentNode.removeChild(elementToRemove)
  }
</script>
```

Study it carefully and apply to yours needs. Example is very simple so you should have no problems to understand it.

Comment: i do not want to write cell1 , cell2 .... every time,i think it should be a loop .
i want to add new row for all columns with same properties of old rows last cell have button

Comment: so change that for what you need, this is only example, I will no write entire logic for you.